Homotopy coherence datum for composition of Becker-Gottlieb transfers
I have a question about certain detail in following answer by Denis Nardin adressing the concept of presheaves with transfer (mostly known in constructions in motivic homotopy theory) from viewpoint of classical stable homotopy theory.
The rough summary is that the notion of a "transfer" appears already (... or phrased differently has it's counterpart) in classical SHT in guise of so called Becker-Gottlieb transfer which to a map $f: X \to Y$ of top spaces (#Correction: (thanks to John Rognes' remark) BG is not defined for arbitrary $f$; but let assume for those maps and their compositions we are considering in this question in is assumed to be defined)
associates in category $\text{Sp}$ of spectra certain map
$f^*: \Sigma^\infty_+Y\to \Sigma^\infty_+X$ for which for composition $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g} Z$ the equation $g^*f^*=(gf)^*$ is literally an equality only after passing to homotopy category (...and so "rectifiyng" the functoriality). In other words, one may think of this equality (...in spirit of $\infty$-categorical philosophy) as a rather compliciated datum of a homotopy between the two maps (then with coherent homotopies of homotopies on the "next" layer, and so on ...); at all a rather complicated datum.
But instead of working directly with spectra (which may be regarded as space-valued homology functors $\mathrm{Top}\to \mathrm{Top}_*$ & some consistence conditions), one could also study functors $\mathrm{Cor}\to \mathrm{Top}_* $ (from the category $ \mathrm{Cor}$ of correspondences & some consistence conditions; see the linked discussion for details), which turns of to be given as $D(\mathbb{Z})$, the derived cat of $\mathbb{Z}$ endowed with natural forgetful functor $D(\mathbb{Z})\to \mathrm{Sp}$ to the cat of spectra identifying $D(\mathbb{Z})$ with spectra carying additionally $H\mathbb{Z}$-module structure.
The pun seems to be that if we restrict to the coherence conditions for compositions of Becker-Gottlieb transfers given above to those spectra inside $D(\mathbb{Z})$, then according to the statement in the linked answer these "hold on the nose".
Question: And exactly this point I not completely understand. What does here mean that these coherences conditions on the transfers "hold on the nose" if we restrict ourself to $D(\mathbb{Z})$.
In the answer is stated that the mapping spaces to $D(\mathbb{Z})$ is given dy $X \mapsto C_*(X)$ (ie associating ato $X$ it's complex and pass to derived cat of complexes).
The latter formulation suggests that working inside $D(\mathbb{Z})$
makes the coherences conditions on the composition of Becker-Gottlieb transfers in certain way more "amenable"/ "nicer"/ better behaved/controllable in certain sense (?) justifying the formulation that in $D(\mathbb{Z})$ these hold more or less "on the nose" in contrast to the "messy" datum if we work in $\text{Sp}$ instead.
What are the advantages of this viewpoint and in which sense in $D(\mathbb{Z})$ the coherence relations hold more or less "on the nose"? Does this mean that in $D(\mathbb{Z})$  these can be written down explicitly , while in $\text{Sp}$ they exist only abstractly?

(1) The Becker-Gottlieb transfer is only defined for some maps f : X --> Y, not "every map" as you write.
(2) By "pun", do you mean "punchline"?  (3) To say that a diagram commutes "on the nose" means that it is defined and commutes in an underlying 1-category, not just up to homotopy or up to coherent homotopies.  The idiom may come from radio broadcasting, referring to a gesture indicating that the program is right on schedule.

@JohnRognes: right, thanks (...by the way is there a precise chracterization of those map for which BG transfer is welldefined?) Let assume we dealing with maps for which und whose compositions BG transfer is declared! And yes, "punchline".

This problem is not fully settled.  There is recent progress in the Sp case by Maxime Ramzi, Marc Volpe and Sebastian Wolf, but I have not seen a preprint.  If that is of interest to you, you could contact them.  Or do you only care about the D(Z) case?

@JohnRognes: I would happy about any insight in setting of $D(\mathbb{Z})$

@JohnRognes: On (3): But then I'm a bit confused about the formulation of "Now the coherences conditions on the transfers hold on the nose." (relatively at the end of the quoted answer). If this "on the nose" idiom means in this context that the diagram between $g^f^$ and $(gf)^$ commutes honestly (ie inside underlying $1$-cat without "higher corrections"  as you wrote), which meaning do have the "coherences conditions" at that point? Aren't "coherence conditions" comming intrinsically from $\infty$ setting? But if  $g^f^$ and $(gf)^$ commute already on usual $1$-categorical level, which

meaning does have the term "coherence conditions" in the quoted sentence?

$\newcommand{\S}{\mathcal S}
\newcommand{\Top}{\mathrm{Top}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\Span}{\mathrm{Span}}
\newcommand{\Fin}{\mathrm{Fin}}
\newcommand{\Fun}{\mathrm{Fun}}$
This is a bit too long for a comment, but maybe not a full answer.
First, let me make a small comment about Becker-Gottlieb (=BG) transfers : they are not defined for arbitrary maps, and even in the generality in which they are defined, they are not even known to compose up to homotopy (as John says in the comments, progress has been made in this direction, but the general question is still open). Denis' answer was about the case of finite covering maps ("more generally" maps with homotopy fibers given by finite sets), where they are known to indeed compose, and in fact, up to higher coherences and so on.
Now, about coherences. Before answering about BG transfers, let me deal with a simpler case: maps between finite sets. Let $\Span(\Fin)$ denote the category of spans of finite sets - its objects are finite sets and morphisms spans. In that case, $E_\infty$-groups (and indeed, monoids) can be encoded as functors $\Span(\Fin)\to \S$ preserving finite products - here I mean $\infty$-functor, so with homotopies, coherences etc.
But such a functor $\Span(\Fin)\to \Top$, the $1$-category of topological spaces, corresponds to a classical commutative monoid in topological spaces, i.e. topological monoid, and say, group if I assume an extra "grouplikeness" condition. Now, any such thing, when postcomposed along $\Top\to\S$  corresponds to a $\Z$-module in $E_\infty$-groups, and in particular is an Eilenberg-MacLane space, while there are (very much) non EM $E_\infty$-monoids.
So here, strictifying a functor amounts to making it have a $\Z$-linear structure. This is the general slogan underlying Denis' answer : if you ask for too much strictification on your higher alebraic structures, you'll end up asking for $\Z$-linearity.
You can make this a bit more precise: the $\infty$-category $\Fun^\times(\Span(\Fin),\Top)[W^{-1}]$ where $W$ is the class of pointwise weak-equivalences (and $\Fun^\times$ means preserving products up to homeomorphism) is equivalent to $D_{\geq 0}(\Z)$. Well, not quite - I haven't imposed the grouplikeness condition, but if I do, then it becomes true. Without the grouplikeness condition, this is $\mathrm{Mod}_\mathbb N(\mathrm{CMon}(\S))$. On the other hand, $\Fun^\times(\Span(\Fin),\S)$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{CMon}(\S)$ or, with the grouplike condition, to $\mathrm{CGrp}(\S)\simeq\mathrm{Sp}_{\geq 0}$.
In this sense, while (connective) spectra are like "commutative groups in spaces where all the axioms hold up to coherent homotopy", (connective) $\Z$-modules are like "commutative groups in spaces where all the axioms hold 'strictly'". Of course this is a bit hard to express intuitively without details because there are still (/there can still be) homotopies and higher coherences, but the idea is that they can be strictified. A key example to always keep in mind is the example of $\eta\in\pi_1(\mathbb S)$. Let me make that more precise: one algebraic and ahistorical interpretation of $\eta$ is as a default in "strict commutativity": if $x\in \pi_0(X)$, where $X$ is an $E_\infty$-group, then $\eta x\in \pi_1(X)$ can be interpreted as follows : there is a commutativity homotopy $h_{y,z} : yz \simeq zy$ coming from the $E_\infty$-structure on $X$. Plugging in $(y,z)=(x,x)$
gives you a specific homotopy $h_{x,x} : x^2\simeq x^2$ which is typically not the trivial loop, and hence gives you an element of $\pi_1(X)$ (using grouplikeness to make it a loop around $0$ rather than $x^2$). If $X$ could be strictified, because $\eta$ maps to $\eta$ under functors, it would follow that $\eta x = 0$ for all $x$. This "corresponds" to the fact that $\eta\mapsto 0$ under $\mathbb S\to \Z$ and that strictifiable commutative monoids admit a $\Z$-module structure.
Hopefully, for $\Span(\Fin)$, this makes the claim in Denis' answer somewhat clearer.
For the category of correspondences with covering maps as backwards maps replacing $\Span(\Fin)$, the story becomes a bit more complicated because you have to impose certain conditions to ensure some kind of "descent" - I guess Denis' answer puts this under the rug with "satisfying some conditions", but the moral story should be the same.
EDIT to answer the comments below:

In the above answer, I should have specified that $\S$ denotes the $\infty$-category of spaces, not of spectra. $E_\infty$-monoids or groups are then defined as functors $\Fin_*\to \S$ satisfying certain so-called Segal conditions; or equivalently product-preserving functors $\Span(\Fin)\to \S$. The equivalence is not trivial, but true nonetheless. Here, $\Span(\Fin)$ is not the nerve of a $1$-category : $\Fin$ is, but in the span category one is supposed to allow for composition (given by pullbacks) to be defined only up to equivalence. In particular, $\Span(\Fin)$ is a $(2,1)$-category - for general $C$ with pullbacks, $\Span(C)$ is defined and studied in Barwick's Spectral Mackey functors and algebraic K-theory (I)

A precise formulation of strictification is what I mentioned in the 4th paragraph: a lift of the product-preserving functor $\Span(\Fin)\to\S$ to a (product preserving) functor $\Span(\Fin)\to \Top$ - note that since $\Top$ is a $1$-category, this means among other things that this will factor through $\mathrm{ho}(\Span(\Fin))$ and correspond to a classical functor $\mathrm{ho}(\Span(\Fin))\to \Top$, that is, one where everything commutes strictly. In particular, this is not saying that the functor $\Span(\Fin)\to \S$ itself involves diagrams that "commute strictly", but it can be lifted to an ordinary functor between $1$-categories where everything does commute strictly.



Thank you for the answer. There are a couple rather basic aspects I would like to develop better understanding for, could you borrow some time to make a few comments on them? Let's focus for sake of simplicity as you suggested in the answer to the case $\text{Span}(\text{Fin})$ only. (1) With which definition for $E_{\infty}$ monoids& groups you are working above? A recomendable source? (so far I was reading your answer I interpreted the notion for $E_{\infty}$ monoids (groups) as

monoid (group) objects inside the stable $(\infty,1)$-category of spectra, which you denoted by $\mathcal S$; but I'm not sure if in this specific context of this answer probably a different definition is better suited to think of them).
The reason why I'm asking this is because you refered to a result that $E_{\infty}$-monoids (groups, if we add some additional cond's) are encoded as $\infty$-functors $\text{Span}(\text{Fin})\to \mathcal{S}$ preserving finite limits. Firstly, if I'm not missing something, the $1$-cat $\text{Span}(\text{Fin})$ is tacitly turned

to $\infty$-cat by Nerve construction, right?
And the point is that I have the feeling that with "appropriate" definition of a $E_{\infty}$-monoid (group) the quoted correspondence should manifest more or less "tautologically", but from this "monoid/group object inside spectra" definition I supposed to use I
not see how it should follow immediately. A guess: Does there exist a definition of $E_{\infty}$-monoid(group) tautologically in terms of such maps $\text{Span}(\text{Fin})\to \mathcal{S}$?

(2): So the "commutative groups" vs $\mathbb{Z}$-modules in connective spectra is about how lax vs strict the commutativity of the arrows witnessing the axioms are formulated. Could you elaborate a bit more procisely what you mean by, that for the latter (ie the $\mathbb{Z}$-modules "there are still (/there can still be) homotopies and higher coherences, but the idea is that they can be strictified."?
Is there a kind of "machinery" for this "strictifying" in context of $\infty$-cats involved? (assuming one knows, thatan object is "strictifiable" abstractly?

A guess: Could this attribute that such spectrum can be stratified be formalized in terms of something like that if a spectrum has structure a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then it can be "strictified" in the sense that there exist a in appropriate sense equivalent spectrum (kind of "replacing" object) where the arrows witnessing the axioms commute literally strictly? Or is there something differently involved behind "strictifiability" (in $\infty$-cat sense)?

(3) About the idiom, that as Denis Nardin used that in $D(\mathbb{Z})$ the coherences conditions "hold on the nose": So if I understand it correctly now then this "holding on the nose" should be regard as synonymously to that these are "strictifiable" in the way you explained, right? In other words, once we have performed this mysterious "strictification", the arrows commute as in $1$-cat. Especially, this formulation says not something about that these coherences conditions can be writen down explicitly (...as I initially seemingly incorrectly interpreted from the choice of words? :)

I've added edits at the bottom of my answer to hopefully clarify some of these points

Thank you! Two points I still not understand: Firstly, in the "You can make this a bit more precise" paragraph you remarked that there are equivalences between $\text{Fun}^\times(\text{Span}(\text{Fin}),\text{Top})[W^{-1}]$ (+ certain grouplike condition) and $D_{\geq 0}(\mathbb{Z})$, and also between $\mathrm{CGrp}(\mathcal{S}) $ and $\mathrm{Sp}_{\geq 0}$. Could you give a reference where proofs of these statements are discussed?

Another point, about the heuristic example you gave in next paragraph, is there a reason from "classical" (=non infty-categorical)  homotopy theory of spectra) why if we take such an object $\eta\in\pi_1(\mathbb S)$ and a $x\in \pi_0(X)$ the "productlike looking" object $\eta x$ just from pure formal reasons "lands" inside $ \pi_1(X)$? (i.e. from where "multiplying" with $\eta$ causes this "shift by $1$ for the elemnts in the homotopy grps of $X$

The second equivalence, namely between $E_\infty$-groups and connective spectra is known as "May's recognition principle", which should help you find suitable references (I can give some $\infty$-categorical ones, I'm afraid I'm not very knowledgeable about older literature). The first one comes from combining two things:  for $C$ an ordinary category with finite products, $Fun^\times(Span(Fin),C) = CMon(C)$ (and the grouplike condition corresponds to landing in $CGrp(C)$), together with the fact the quillen equivalences $CGrp(Top) = CGrp(sSet) = sAb = Ch_{\geq 0}(\mathbb Z)$

(I wrote "$=$" but they are only Quillen equivalences) For your other question, yes: generally, there is a map $\pi_n(X) \otimes \pi_m(Y)\to\pi_{n+m}(X\wedge Y)$ which ultimately comes from the fact that $S^n\wedge S^m = S^{n+m}$ . Taking $Y$ to be the sphere spectrum and $m=1$ should give you this "shift"

yes, I would definitely appreciate references treating it $\infty$-categorically

Recently I have pondered again about this issue on BG transfers, rasing another question "conflating" a bit the terminology you used in the answer with what Denis Nardin used in the linked discussion. Could you if you have some time briefly look through?

Firstly, you gave above an equivalence on level of $\infty$-cats between $D_{\geq 0}(\Bbb Z)$ and $\text{Fun}^\times(\text{Span}(\text{Fin}),\text{Top})[W^{-1}]$, especially in light of this equivalence you automatically regard $D_{\geq 0}(\Bbb Z)$ as $\infty$-cat. But there is also a classical $1$-cat notion of derived cat  $D_{\geq 0}(\Bbb Z)$ (eg used in Denis Nardin's answer modulo trunication to positive degrees), which can canonically regarded as strict $\infty$-cat having only trivial higher morphisms.

Does the $D_{\geq 0}(\Bbb Z)$ you consider in the quoted $\infty$-cat equivalence above coincide with the latter $1$-cat version $D_{\geq 0}(\Bbb Z)$ upgraded to strict infty cat in the naive way described above, or do you distinct between these two objects?

The second question: Roughly the upshot in Denis Nardin's answer is  there is this usual functor associating with a space $X$ a spectrum $\Sigma^\infty_+X$ with additional feature that for "nice enough" class of maps $f:X \to Y$ (... with finite & discrete homotopy fibers) there exist these BG transfers $f^*:\Sigma^\infty_+Y\to \Sigma^\infty_+X$ for which the compositions of maps behaves highly $\infty$-categorical with all these horrible cohenrences of coherences and so forth. Now the pun was that we have also $D(\mathbb{Z})\to \mathrm{Sp}$ through which we can the

complex $C_*(X)$ and working inside   $D(\mathbb{Z})$ the coherences "repairing" the defect of non $1$-cat'cal behavior of compositions of BG-transfers "hold on the nose", namely (...so far I understood correctly) in the sense of existence of a strictification (in the sense of a lift to a "honest $1$-functor" as you described in last paragraph. That's the rough summary how I understood it.

Now, how does the BG-transfer map look like intermediately inside $D(\mathbb{Z})$, ie as a map of complexes $f^:C_(Y) \to C_(X)$, ie before being sended further to $f^:\Sigma^\infty_+Y\to \Sigma^\infty_+X$? Does it admit at level of complexes explicit heuristic description?
